# UILabel truncate even when it has remaining lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

**Current Behaviour**

I have a multiLine `UILabel` with a Rectangular frame of a particular size.
The font and all is so set that it will display a MAX of three lines and beyond that it will truncate.

**Exceptional Behaviour**

Exceptional behaviour is that sometimes I do have a complete Line or Two remaining but the line truncates. This is because the word at the end of the line is too Big to fit in the end of that line.

**Expected Behaviour**

I wish that the `UILabel` fills to all three Lines and then truncate.

This is my current code

```
[_detailedTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[_detailedTextLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
[_detailedTextLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```

Comment: Just remove the lineBreakMode since NSLineBreakModeWordWrap is default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another line breaking mode.

```
[_detailedTextLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

and also ensure that label has proper height (given that `width` is already set):

```
CGSize size = [_detailedTextLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
_detailedTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
```

Comment: actually it was the issue with height of the label. Thanx @Michal

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one. You need to write these two line.

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: what's height of your label ?